# ubuntu stream microphone to dlna in near real time

Tags: pulseaudio, ffmpeg, dlna, minidlna, rygel

I want to use 14.04 to stream LineIn or microphone out to my cinema-theather,
I used this tips:
http://oliversmith.io/technology/2012/01/10/streaming-audio-from-ubuntu-linux-to-a-dlna-player-blu-ray-or-ps3/
but latency of pulseaudio/pulseaudio-eqilizer/rygel is near by 7-10 sec,it is not good for microphone conference.
Can anybody answer about latency of using ffmpeg or minidlna ? 
or any striming method mic to dlna with low latency